# XSS Risk at $.ajax(options) for the call operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xss, fortify

I have a post type ajax call, which reads data from the UI (dropdowns) and creates a record in background. This is done using a 'callTest' function in js , the function is written as such '$.ajax(options)' would be the last line.

The issue is , Fortify scan shows a dom-based xss risk at the last line pointing to 'options'.

I have tried multiple sorts of encoding (encodeURI, encodeURIComponent, encode.ForHtml) for options, but I get an error saying 'Encoder is not defined' (which is strange because I used the same keywords in different functions in the same js file).

function callTest
I have tried adding content type as '$.ajax({contentType:"application/json"},options)', but then the application breaks.

How can I resolve this risk, please help

Comment: `at the last line pointing to 'options'.` ... so ... what is `options`? why can't you post the code? `$.ajax({contentType:"application/json"},options)` makes no sense ... perhaps you meant to add `contentType` to `options` ...

Comment: In the options object passed to $.ajax(),  most of the parameters are static so they're relatively safe. What about the URL that you're posting to ? Does it rely on any user entered data ?